# made a <div> display:block with onmouseover() but i can't click on it becasue as soon as I move my mouse away it disappears because of onmouseout()

Tags: javascript, html, display, onmouseover, onmouseout

So I made a  display: block when the mouse hovers over a certain , and display: none when the cursor moves away. '

[A div I have made that displays only when the mouse hovers over a certain link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3Zz.png)

[the div has a display: none when the mouse moves away from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afbPC.png)

this is the code I have used

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="LoginShow()" onmouseout="LoginHide()">Login/Sign Up</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function LoginShow (){
document.getElementById("log").style.display="block";}


function LoginHide(){
document.getElementById("log").style.display="none";}
```

But I can't click on the div because as soon as I try to move my cursor to the buttons in the div, the div goes to display none as I have to move my cursor away from the link.

I am new to JS, but I have seen other web pages do it, what's the way for the div to display on mouseover and can be clicked on and goes to display: none only when I move away from the div.

I have also tried

```
 <a href="#" onmouseover="LoginShow()">Login/Sign Up</a> 
 <div class="login" id="log" onmouseover="LoginShow()" 
 onmouseout="LoginHide()">
```

It kind of solves the problem, but for the div to go to display none I have to move the cursor away from the div, if the move the cursor away from the anchor tag, it doesn't go away.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: To improve/clarify the question, please use the "edit" link on the question rather than posting code in comments. But again, please do a complete snippet (see above), that makes it much easier for people to help you and prevents misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without any js, take a look at below snippet.

```js
let target = document.getElementById('target');

function showLog() {
  target.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideLog() {
  target.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #eee;
}

.wrapper .inner-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" onmouseover="showLog()" onmouseout="hideLog()">
  I am the wrapper
  <div class="inner-content" id="target">
    <p>Here is some content inside wrapper element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this I figured, but is there a way to do it with JS? I wanted to do this with JS as I am learning it right now.

Comment: Sure, I editet my response and  implemented the same by using  `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event in JS

Answer (score 0):

i think it can be done with css selectors as you can make other div as the switch to change other elements.
[Reference for css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

And i think your div is part of button which is the reason why they disappear. if that is the case then you should try giving your button "position:relative" and then your div element the "position:absolute". it might work.

Edited:
here is what i tried, its not appealing but just look at it, if it is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
function LoginShow (){
    document.getElementById("log").style.display="block";
}
    

function LoginHide(){
    document.getElementById("log").style.display="none";
}
```

```css
.container{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:lightgreen;
    border:1px red solid;
}
#log{
    background:#efefef;
    padding:20px; 
    width:100px;
    text-align: center;
     display:none;
}
.log>button{
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" onmouseover="LoginShow()" onmouseout="LoginHide()">Login/Sign Up</a>
        <div id="log" onmouseover="LoginShow()" onmouseout="LoginHide()"><button>Sign Up</button></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, the button is inside the div, idk if you have seen the images on not, but the div displays when hovered over the anchor tag, and then you can click on the "log in/sign up" button if you move away from the anchor tag or the div (when displayed), it goes away, that's the idea.

Comment: Try to keep the title / subject of the question short so that it reaches more people by not spending too much time in reading it.